# Can't connect to parse server from devices where the app installed not from developing computer

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, testflight

The app uses parse.com as a back end. On devices with the app installed from computer used in development all works perfectly. But on devices where the app installed from App Store the connection to parse while creating an account or logging in failed.

What may be the reason?

Comment: 1) Are you sure that the device has access to the internet 2) if it's a corporate environment the API you try to call might be on a blacklist?

Comment: Internet connection is there for sure. I tried devices with different env. (

Few times it could login, but in a weird manner - the wheel on login page of the app was spinning and login was not proceeding. After terminating the app and restarting it didn't ask to login and proceed further. But when user tried actions which need queries to parse it was spinning forever.

Comment: Another option might be that you do something different in Release mode than in Debug - if you run your app on a device directly from your Mac by default (if you don't change this) it'll run in Debug configuration and when you submit it to the App Store / Apple TestFlight the Archive (.ipa) file is compiled with Release configuration (once again, unless you change this).

Comment: Thank you. The only thing that may be different if a provisioning profile (created for push notifications). Could it be an issue?

Comment: Now even from my device it fails. Error 100 - something wrong with connection.

Comment: If the issue is not related to push notifications then I don't think that it could affect it, at least it should not (unless you do different things related to whether push notifications are received, blocking login in some way, but this is highly unlikely :) )

Comment: It definitely seems to be a connection issue if it's not related to Debug/Release configuration differences.

Comment: Thank for your attention to my trouble. What I have done is removing the app installed on my iPhone through my laptop. Then I add myself to external users, downloaded the app through TestFlight. When I tried to login the wheel is spinning forever. 
When I do some queries it spins constantly..

One more interesting thing. The login wheel is spinning and I terminate the app. When I launch it next time - login page never shows up - I go inside and I am logged in and profile's data is loading.

Comment: I noticed that only those loading get stuck which are coded with construction - dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
});

Inside this block I call parse methods like getDataInBackgroung. 

Could it be weak place causing spinning situation?